# Why the following query results in an exception?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, llblgenpro, llblgen

The following query results in the exception:

"**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedConstantExpression' to type 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionClasses.SetExpression'.**".

What could be the problem?

```
return (from ubt in meta.TableUbt
        join tc in meta.TableTc on ubt.TCId equals tc.Id
        where ubt.Ar110aid == ar110AId && tc.IsPayment
        group ubt by new { ubt.Ar110aid, ubt.TCId } into tempTrans
        join pyd in meta.TablePyd on tempTrans.Key.Ar110aid equals pyd.Ar110Aid
        join pm in meta.TablePm on pyd.Ar110Id equals pm.Id
        join tly in TableTly on new { pyd.TyId, ChrgTransId = tempTrans.Key.TCId }
              equals new { tly.TyId, tly.ChrgTransId }
        join cr in meta.TableCr on
        new
        {
            TyId = (int?)pyd.TyId,
            TxLevId = (int?)tly.TxLevId,
            Ar101Id = (int?)pm.Ar101Id
        }
        equals
        new
        {
            cr.TyId,
            cr.TxLevId,
            cr.Ar101Id
        }
        join crd in meta.TableCrd on cr.Id equals crd.TableCrId
        where crd.StartingLimit <= tempTrans.Sum(b => b.Amount) && 
              tempTrans.Sum(b => b.Amount) <= crd.EndingLimit
        select crd.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably problem is in joining on **TableTly**. It seems to be local data set. and it's prohibited to join Db data and in-memory objects.